# language specific virtual keyboard with java

Tags: java, layout, keyboard, mapping

I have to make an on-screen keyboard using JAVA on linux.
the problem is it has to work on the most languages.

for start, i need to et the current locale, that's clear, but after that, is there any way of getting the keyboard layout and maping of that locale?

i searched for hours, but couldn't find a thing, so i really hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance, Adam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the keymap files on a typical unix system (/usr/share/keymaps on my linux system).

However, it might be tricky to map between locales and keymaps.

Also, it's worth remembering that locale isn't the only thing affecting the keymap - some people use Dvorak keyboards etc.

Comment: I think i can work with this, if there's a way to get the currently used keymap from the OS. is it possible from JAVA? os is there a file representing the current settings somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, Wikipedia has a pretty complete article on [keyboard layouts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) for various languages, with illustrations.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to get the layouts from a built in source, because it has to work with nearly every language, and it's not an option to hardcode each of them.